# How to display custom database field in M2

Tags: magento2, database

I created a custom db table inside my Magento2 database and am having trouble making my custom phtml file display the field. (I'm new to M2 and php)

Here's my code and when I echo $result it display properly on the website but when I try to display the field with the last line it breaks the page:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think your code is perfect except table name. Try below code.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('custom_catalog_product_other');

//Select Data from table
$sql = "Select * FROM " . $tableName;
$result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
```

Comment: That doesn't work because when you add $resource->getTableName it alters "custom_catalog_product_other" to make it "mg2_custom_catalog_product_other".

Comment: Yes. It will add prefix if you have any. From where you are calling your connection? This que might helps you : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88128/how-to-call-direct-sql-queries-and-join-to-collection-in-magento2

Comment: I'm just saying that snippet wasn't on there because it adds the prefix and doesn't solve the issue of $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql); breaking the page and not displaying the results.  "custom_catalog_product_other" is the correct tablename.