# Magento 2 - How to manipulate tables directly from php

Tags: magento2, database

What classes can I use to directly manipulate Magento database tables? I have created a table in the database and would like to be able to insert/update rows in it directly, without having to define a model class, etc. It seems that `Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb` has the functionality I need, but I'm not sure if I should be using an abstract class directly. Are there any concrete implementations of the class that are designed to be used for my purpose?

Comment: Any further context? You shouldn't be running direct queries unless absolutely necessary. If you have a legitimate reason, great--but if it's laziness, get over it and do it right. Creating a table-linked model is not much different from M1.

Comment: I have a table that is mapping order id's to status ('pending', 'approved', 'declined'). The merchant would like to be sent an email every time a customer tries to place an order, and he wants to manually approve or decline it through custom backend module which lists all orders . All the order information I need is already in the `sales_order` table, so I thought that the two obvious options I had were to either add a column on the `sales_order` table directly which means I also have to modify `Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface` class, or I could create table mapping order id to status.

Comment: Okay, that's fair. You should look at Extension Attributes and joining, then.

Comment: @RyanH. care to post it as a full answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comments, your specific situation is best accomplished in Magento 2 via Extension Attributes. Extension Attributes are the M2 way of adding custom data fields to existing models. In the process, you get out-of-box support for your new attribute in internal and external APIs (and IDE autocompletion).

Create your custom schema (table with the primary key and your custom data columns), then define the extension attribute to join your table. You'll still need to handle saving yourself, via plugins.

See the official documentation on extension attributes here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html

Also see this discussion on implementing an extension attribute in practice, including examples: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92054/1905

---

To answer to your original question: Yes, it is still possible to directly query the database. **You should not do this unless absolutely necessary**. If you are working with a model, follow best practices and use the ORM layer (the model, resource model, and collection). Laziness or ignorance is not an excuse. Learn and use Magento's architecture the way it's meant to be; you'll save a lot of headaches and possible security problems in the process. If you don't know how it works, read [Alan Storm's explanation](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_crud_models_for_database_access).

With that disclaimer out of the way: To perform a manual query, you want to use dependency injection to get an instance of `\Magento\Framework\App\Resource $resource` in your class. Once you have that, `$connection = $resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);` will give you a database connection.

Note that this connection is an instance of [`\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php). As of version 2.1, it's still built on `Zend_Db`, so the methods available from here are very similar to what you would have on Magento 1.

Also see this discussion for an example on injecting and using this. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/88129/1905