# How to add quote Item id as new field?

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, addtocart, sales, sales-quote

I have a new field `varient_id` in `sales_flat_quote_item` and `sales_flat_order_item` table.

I want to save `item_id` as **varient_id** in `sales_flat_quote_item` and `sales_flat_order_item` table. ie,quote `item_id` as quote `varient_id` and `order item_id` as `order item_id`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beste way i think is creating a observer on the `sales_model_service_quote_submit_after` action and there manipulate the database to process the data needed. hope this helps.

In config.xml

```
<sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>
            <observers>
                <set_itemid>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Company_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>setVariantId</method>
                </set_itemid>
            </observers>
    </sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>
```

In Observer

```
  public function setVariantId($observer)
    {               
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $orderId = $order->getId();
        $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
        foreach($orderItems as $item){      

                $parentId = 0;
                $orderItemCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter('quote_item_id', $item->getVariantId())
                            ->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $orderId);
                foreach($orderItemCollection as $col){
                    $parentId = $col->getItemId();              
                }
                if($parentId){
                    $item->setVariantId((int)$parentId);
                    $item->save();
                }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution here for Magento 2. I am sharing this for basic Idea. You can create an observer in 1.9 for `sales_model_service_quote_submit_after` in your XML file.

```
<events>
    <sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>
        <observers>
            <onepagecheckout>
                <type>model</type>
                <class>onepagecheckout/observer</class>
                <method>saveData</method>
            </onepagecheckout>
        </observers>
    </sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>
</events>
```

In observer file you can update your item ID. Here is the code that we need to add observer file.

```
protected $_checkoutSession;
public function __construct ( \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $_checkoutSession ) {
    $this->_checkoutSession = $_checkoutSession;
}
public function saveData(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
  $cartData = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach( $cartData as $item ):
        /* Here we can manipulate data */
    endforeach;
    $cartData->save();
}
```

for manipulate database and to process data you need block or model files. you also need to initialize resource, then you need to call connection. I hope it will give you an idea to save `varient_id`. Also here is a link can help you that How to manipulate db tables [helplink1](http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-insertupdate-multiple-records-to-database-in-magento-2/) [helplink2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120920/magento-2-how-to-manipulate-tables-directly-from-php)