# How to get products name and sku and url key using sql query in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, database, sql, programmatically

> How to get products name and sku and url key  using sql query in  magento 2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SQL QUERY (Magento 2.1 and earlier):**

```
SELECT nametable.value, 
           nametable.store_id, 
           catalog_product_entity.sku 
FROM   `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS nametable 
           LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity 
                  ON nametable.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id 
WHERE  nametable.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id 
                                     FROM   `eav_attribute` 
                                     WHERE  `entity_type_id` = 4 
                                            AND `attribute_code` LIKE 'name')
```

**SQL QUERY (Magento 2.2 and later):**

```
SELECT nametable.value, 
   nametable.store_id, 
   catalog_product_entity.sku 
FROM   `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS nametable 
   LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity 
          ON nametable.row_id = catalog_product_entity.row_id 
WHERE  nametable.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id 
                             FROM   `eav_attribute` 
                             WHERE  `entity_type_id` = 4 
                                    AND `attribute_code` LIKE 'name')
```

As mentioned by **Shashank Kumrawat**, *Sku value is stored in catalog_product_entity and  name* field value is stored in `catalog_product_entity_varchar`

> As Magento  support multi-store data, So for  single SKU, multiple row
> can be exits.catalog_product_entity_varchar have store id field.If you >> want specific store name then just  nametable.store_id = {StoreId}

Comment: perfect answer with explanation!!! made my day! +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use directly sql queries in magento2 as shown on this link -

using object manager (not recommended)

> https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-write-custom-mysql-query/

Without object manager (recommended)

> [How to call Direct SQL Queries and join to collection In Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88128/how-to-call-direct-sql-queries-and-join-to-collection-in-magento2)

To get **SKU**, you need to use table `catalog_product_entity`

and to get **product name**, need to use table `catalog_product_entity_varchar`

Answer (score 1):

For Magento 2.2x versions, use row_id instead of entity_id in above sql queries